# how to stop iMessage link preview from rotating image

Tags: imessage, share-open-graph

When sharing links from my website, sometimes the images are rotated 90 degrees.

```
https://dw2h1frcjb7pw.cloudfront.net/1a5765ac5b5e7c0356a5eaf208c53a290fd8497ef1907e32212888f1c2094cbd
```

https://primitives.xyz/claim/1aE14KJuHOQKkbP5cjtMsV

How do I fix this? In all my extensions for testing previews it displays correctly.

Comment: The image you show is rotated by 90 Deg CCW in the exif data.